# Placeholder image when there is no connectivity to load image with web service

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, web-services, image

can we get any dummy image when internet connection(or no web services available) is not there ?when we have internet connection i must retrieve image from  the web services....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just have a default image in your project that you load up if you cannot get one from the web service.  I am not sure how you are opening the connection.  If you are getting some sort of data back from a connection do something like this:

```
UIImage *theImage;
if(imageData > 0)
   theImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData]
else
   theImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"whateverYourDummyImageNameIs.jpg"];
```

It really depends on how you are retiriving the image.  When your service finishes, just check to see if you have any data; if yes, save the image.  If no, load the dummy image.